# Xcode 5.1 and tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, picker, xcode5.1

Since Xcode 5.1 upgrade I have some trouble in tableview delegate.

In my app I have tableview that have picker in some of their cells. These cells are show only when the user want to change the value of the picker. The same usage as in calendar when you want to change the date of the appointment.

The problem is that with Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1 the cells with picker are always show even if their height are set to 0.

The workaround I find is to test the cell height at the beginning of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` routine.

Any idea ?

Comment: How do you set height? Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this ...

**Zero height cell**

If you do use this approach, do not forget to set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`. Otherwise content is drawn outside of the cell. You should check/set it on `contentView`, `contentView.superview`.

**Do not use zero height cell**

Simply don't include these cells when they're not needed. And then when you need this cell, just insert it via ...

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

... and when it's no longer needed, remove it via ...

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: I set the height of cell to 0 in heightForRowAtIndexPath. I don't set clipToBounds.

Comment: Set it to `YES` in this case, otherwise you'll see the content on the screen even if the height is `0`. `clipsToBounds` basically says that the view can't draw outside own bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clipping the bounds of the content view?
eg
  cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
  cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

or if within InterfaceBuilder, for the Table View Cell's View properties, 
  check Clip Subviews

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how do you set heights for cells but following UITableViewDelegate's method should work

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL isHidden = // .... your code
    return isHidden ? 0 : another_height;
}
```